# Getting POST : 400 Bad request in angular

Tags: angular, api, postman

I'm trying to fetch details from "http://169.38.82.132:94/token" to "http://localhost:4200/" and am getting a message as "POST : 400 Bad request in angular". My service.ts file is

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PeopleService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
   headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
    'method': 'POST',
     'body': 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=user',      
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  fetchPeople() { return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/token', { headers: this.headers }); };
}
```

I have attached the screenshot of NodeJS code taken from postman.[postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu2yL.png).

[image]

Is I missed any settings

```
var data = "grant_type=password&username=user&password=user"
headers = new HttpHeaders({      
    'method': 'POST',
     //'body': 'grant_type=password&username=user&password=user',      
     'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
);

fetchPeople() {
    return this.http.post('http://169.38.82.132:94/token',data,{ 
        headers: this.headers 
    });
};
```

but same results.

Comment: In your 2nd way of calling the service remove 'method': 'POST' Also please note that you would need to send JSON and your data is string

Comment: Thanks @TARJU, I did as suggested error gone but didnt get any result

Comment: no, this is token request, it is formurlencoded not json string. i suspect your username and password is wrong please cross check with the backend team

Comment: okay do 1 thing in POSTman can you pass your user id and password from Authorization section as shown in pic here https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIHDv.png and let me know

Comment: Yes, @TARJU, as you suggested I pass my username(user) and password (user) from authorization section . Auth section image -  http://sampledemos.online/image/auth.png and Params section image - http://sampledemos.online/image/params.png

Comment: so does that work?

Comment: ok! so whats next we need to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to encode the username and password in the specified format requested by the endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar, username and password is in correct format only as in postman am giving as in the above format.

Answer (score 0):

As a answer one would need to pass user id and password in Authorization section if you are acquiring token from your API.

Much of the details regarding that are already added above please see comments above for more details.